# .net ArcGis update feature returns "Cannot call this method in this context: You must load the feature before editing."

Tags: .net, arcgis

I'm trying to update the attributes of a feature layer through .Net. But I keep getting this error message: "Cannot call this method in this context: You must load the feature before editing."
Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {

  var featureTable = new ServiceFeatureTable(new Uri("https://services7.arcgis.com/yixziXsHssbXEWl5/ArcGIS/rest/services/grex/FeatureServer/0")) {Credential = new ArcGISTokenCredential()};

  ((TokenCredential) featureTable.Credential).Token = GetToken().access_token;
  var queryParams = new QueryParameters {WhereClause = "DeelplanId = 666"};

  // Query the feature table 
  var queryResult =  featureTable.QueryFeaturesAsync(queryParams);
  // Cast the QueryResult to a List so the results can be interrogated
  queryResult.Wait();
  var features = queryResult.Result.ToList();

  features[0].SetAttributeValue("Kosten", 3562);

  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

It fails on the SetAttributeValue, although I see the attributes are loaded from the server.
Any idea?, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature has to be loaded:

var editFeature = features.First();
await (editFeature as ArcGISFeature).LoadAsync();
editFeature.SetAttributeValue("description", $"Updated from runtime at {DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()}");

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/195459-update-feature-returns-cannot-call-this-method-in-this-context-you-must-load-the-feature-before-editing